# navigation drawer menu items should not change colour when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-xml

I have a very simple question:

How do i not make the menu items inside the NavigationDrawer not change their colour and the colour of their background when clicked?

Here is a snapshot of my app:

BEFORE CLICK:
[image]

and here is how it looks After click:

[image]

Here is the xml code of my NavidationDrawer:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer" />
```

Here is the xml code for my NavigationDrawer menu item i.e. activity_navigation_drawer_drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_all_products"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="All Products" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_login_or_register"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Login Or Register" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Manage Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="My Cart" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Contact Us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="About Loyalty Cart" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Additional Features">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_terms_and_conditions"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Terms And Conditions" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: You can use Shareprecenes . When click set text Color and save to SharePrecenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:checkableBehavior="single"` in the **menu** xml file (activity_navigation_drawer_drawer).

Comment: Or simply make it none. for example android:checkableBehavior="none"

Answer (score 0):

** Workaround **

Create a new selector in xml file with same color shape for selected and unselected states. Then set item background to this selector drawable.